# How to display Internet explorer not supported in angular without importing pollyfills

Tags: javascript, html, angular, internet-explorer

With IE officially deprecated in Angular 12, I want to display a static warning in my page to notify the user to switch to a supported browser.

I'm using a simple snippet like this in the index.html
to append a css class to the body, when then displays a div element.

```html
    <body class="mat-typography">
        <script>
            (function msieversion() {
                const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
                const msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
                if (msie > 0) {
                    document.body.classList.add('is-internet-explorer');
                }
            })();
        </script>
        <div class="ie">isIE</div>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
```

```css
.is-internet-explorer {
    .ie {
        display: flex;
    }
    app-root{
        display: none;
    }
}
.ie {
    display: none;
}
```

But I'm getting errors in internet explorer, that runtime.js, polyfills.js, vendor.js and main.js wont run. I assume it is because of missing polyfills and the tsconfig target setting, that these won't run.

[image]

Is there a way to "prevent" angular from inserting or executing these script tags in the first place? I've tried to remove them in my `if (msie > 0)` block, but that doesn't work.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const x = document.body.querySelectorAll('script[defer]');
    x.forEach((i) => document.body.removeChild(i));
});
```

My goal is to accomplish this without having to adjust polyfill and tsconfig settings, to keep the build size to a mininum.

Comment: I wonder if these errors are due to the fact that the scripts are included - or because Angular starts up. You could conditionally prevent angular from booting by checking for IE in main.ts. But not sure if that resolves these errors..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The errors showing in IE is due to the scripts still load in IE. If you don't want to see the errors in IE, you can load an unsupported html page when the browser is IE.

Besides, it seems that there're some issues in your detecting IE code. I made some changes, and you can refer to my steps below, I test it and it works well:

1. Add a **unsupported.html** file in the root of **src** folder. Example **unsupported.html** file:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title></title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <body>
       <h1>The app is not supported in IE. Please use other browsers!</h1>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```
2. Add `"src/unsupported.html"` in **angular.json** `assets` property. For example:

   ```
   "assets": [
             "src/favicon.ico",
             "src/assets",
             "src/unsupported.html"
    ],
   ```
3. Detect browser in **src/index.html**, if IE then redirect to **unsupported.html**, if not then render `<app-root>`. The code is like below:

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>MyApp</title>
     <base href="/">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
   </head>

   <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var msie = /msie\s|trident/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
         if (msie) {
           //IE, redirect page
           window.location.href = "./unsupported.html";
         }
         else {
           //render app
           var elem = document.createElement("app-root");
           document.body.appendChild(elem);
         }
     </script>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to display an alert before IE encounters any problem. I use below code:

```
<body>
  <script>
    function isUserUsingIeBrowser() {
      return /MSIE|Trident/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
    }

    if (isUserUsingIeBrowser()) {
      alert('IE not supported');
    }
  </script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```